# GTX 950M outperformed by integrated graphics?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I'm very confused. I recently purchased [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0146DD02G) laptop, and, it being the first high-end-ish laptop I got, it was is also my first experience with having a GPU.

I quickly learned about the Nvidia control panel and decided to benchmark the GPU with Cinebench (maybe that's the right thing to do, maybe not, I'm not sure). Basically, the GPU (a GTX 950M) got around 15 FPS, while the integrated graphics (Intel HD graphics 520) got a little less than 40 FPS.

Is there something I'm missing here? Is the GPU less powerful? (Doesn't make sense, but I wouldn't know.) Is it just a matter of updating drivers? Please help!

P.S. Any other tips you could give about GPUs in general would be appreciated.

Comment: which benchmark have you used? Have you configured optimus to use the nVIDIA GPU for the benchmark program?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but in the Nividia control panel I kept all the defaults.

Comment: I don't have a nVIDIA in my laptop (I have an AMD and here I can select an exe and set it to high performance and this tells Windows to use the AMD GPU instead of the Intel HD).

Comment: You can try to force which card is being used by going to the Nvidia control panel, then click "Desktop", and then check the box next to the "Run with graphics processor" option. Then rerun CineBench by right clicking cinebench.exe and choosing to use the nvidia card.

Comment: By the way I should have clarified, but I meant I kept all the defaults after selecting the Nividia card as the GPU. Nevertheless I just ran it again and got 40 FPS on the Nividia card. The results seem to vary greatly. I'm still getting a smooth 40 FPS from the intel HD Graphics though and it's results have varied a lot less.

Comment: try a different benchmark tool like 3D Mark: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DMark

Comment: I'll try 3d Mak but for some reason, enabling the Nividia card as my default  under global settings brings the card up to a solid 40 FPS in cinebench.